# question about limit and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

consider  following hypotheses

> - $ m\in\mathbb N$
> - $c\in \mathbb C\,$ ,$\, \; a_j\in \mathbb C$
> - $a_j\in \mathbb C\;$ , $\;|a_j|=1,\;\forall\;1\le j\le m$

if $$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{m}a^n_j=c$$

then how to prove  $ c=m$ and $\forall1\le j\le m\;$ , $\;a_j=1$ .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course $c=m$ follows easily from "$\forall1\le j\le m:a_j=1$". I feel like that is the hard part though.

Comment: I don't see that the limit necessarily converges.  For the case $a_1=1, a_2=-1$ it seems like $\sum_{j=1}^2 a_j^n$ is 2 when $n$ is even and 0 otherwise.  Are you missing some assumption?

Comment: @Peder I think it is implied that the limit exists. I don't mean it  necessarily is a consequence of the hypothesis, I just mean the reader is supposed to assume the limit exists.

Comment: "contest-math"? What contest?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson:this question is from Iran competition  math

Answer (score 3):

Here's an outline: Each $a_j$ is of the form $\exp(\pi i b_j)$. Each $b_j$ can be approximated by a rational number. Then high powers of $a_j$ can be seen to get arbitrarily close to $1$ cyclically, using least common denominators of the $b_j$. This makes the total close to $m$.

And if $k$ of the $a_j$ are not equal to $1$, then high powers of those $a_j$ will cyclically have negative real part, making the total have real part $\le m-k$. Since the limit exists, the only resolution to this is that $k=0$ and they are all equal to $1$.

Again, this is just an outline. All the bits about cycling and closeness would need to be formalized for a solid argument.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, $b_j$ is defined in $[0,1)$ by $a_j=\exp(\pi i b_j)$.

Comment: @alexjordan I had missed that, sorry. I skipped over when I read $\exp$.

Comment: Oops, I guess I meant $[0,2)$ given my parameterization.

Comment: If $b_j=2/3$, then high powers of $a_j$ do not get arbitrarily close to $-1$.

Comment: Thanks @Gerry! Hmm...maybe we can just arrange for high powers to have negative real part.

Comment: It's worth a try.